# Ember JS automatically register directory classes to DI

Tags: ember.js, dependency-injection

Creating `in-repo-addon` in Ember.JS gives a lot of possibilities. Today I've stumbled into a case when I wanted to register all classes in directory (for example `my-dir`) into `Dependency Injector` (same way it's done with `services` by Ember, but I wanted to use some other namespace).

For example I want to allow developer to create multiple classes inside `proxy` directory, and register all of them in DI under `proxy:` namespace. So later we can use:

```
Ember.Component.extend({
  myProxy: Ember.inject('proxy:my'),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do this using an initializer. More details on this here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/applications/dependency-injection/

The hard part may be getting all proxy items in s folder to automatically register ...

**Edit**
Looks like I didn't spend enough time thinking about this. You should be able to do at least part of this easily. There are two parts to this.

### Part 1

Ember currently uses the `ember-resolver` to handle lookups for various items. If you check the tests for the resolver you'll notice that you should be able to map in anything you want: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-resolver/blob/master/tests/unit/resolvers/classic/basic-test.js

So in your case, if you do a `Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('proxy:main')` from within an Ember instantiated class (a route, controller or component for instance) it would look in `app/proxy/main.js` which your addon could be populating.

Details on the `Ember.getOwner` lookup are available here: https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_getOwner

### Part 2

So at this point you can lookup proxies (which would be doable in an `init` method). But if we want to get truly elegant we'd want to allow `Ember.inject.proxy('main')` syntax.

Doing so would involve calling a private method inside of `Ember.inject` in an initializer. Because that naming scheme is changing in the [new Javascript modules RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0176-javascript-module-api.md), it may be unwise to try to add this syntactic sugar ...

So I'd advise avoiding touching that private API unless it's **really important** to your app design.

Comment: I know initializers and instance-initializers well. I just wondered is there an option to automatically register them automatically (so for example addon can let application use given structure).

Comment: Just edited my answer, looks like lookups would be handled for you easily